# mariadb connection pool: what is the difference between connection_count and pool_size

Tags: mariadb, connection-pooling

Hi i am playing around with mariadb connection pools and multiprocessing in python.

I wanted to observer how many connections of the pool are in use. Regarding the documentation https://mariadb-corporation.github.io/mariadb-connector-python/pool.html there are two properties:

```
ConnectionPool.connection_count
   Returns the number of connections in connection pool.
```

and

```
ConnectionPool.pool_size
   Returns the size of the connection pool.
```

but what ever I configure as pool_size during initiation of the pool both properties are showing exactly the same which is the defined pool size. I printed right after initialization of the pool and during the call of a function which calls get_connection() every time.

I was expecting that the connection_count would show me the amount of connections I have fetched with the get_connection function.

Is there another way to observer the used connections to prevent the code from running into the out of connections exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pool_size` returns a constant value which was specified when creating the pool, e.g. pool_size=10. connection_count returns the number of (used and unused) connections in the pool.

The values of pool_size and connection_count should be usually the same, but they can differ, e.g. if a connection could not be resetted or an automatic reconnect failed.

column_count property just returns the sum of used and free connections:

```
return len(self._connections_free + self._connections_used)
```

So to determine the number of used/unused connections just check the values of

```
len(pool._connections_free)
```

and

```
len(pool._connections_used)
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work, although I set pool_size=5 and always see 4 free an 1 used connection. Looks like I need to dig further how to use more connections in parallel